# SQL Query to MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a section of SQL code that can be run to show age buckets of a particular workload. Due to some system changes i will soon not be able to access this database through SQL and I do not really follow it.

please can someone help me convert this into an MS Access Query, I have included the SQL and Results below,

**SQL**

```
Use MoxieApp
select
b.mailboxid,
b.Name as 'Mailbox',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '1',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '1' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '2',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '2' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '3',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '3' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '4',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '4' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '5',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '5' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '6',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '6' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '7',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '7' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '8',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '8' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '9',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '9' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '10',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '10' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '11',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '11' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '12',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '12' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '13' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '13',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '13' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '14' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '14',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '14' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '15' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '15',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '15' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '16' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '16',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '16' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '17' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '17',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '17' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '18' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '18',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '18' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '19' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '19',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '19' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '20' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '20',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '20' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '21' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '21',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '21' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '22' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '22',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '22' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '23' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '23',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '23' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '24' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '24',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '24' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '48' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '48',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '48' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '72' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '72',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '72' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '96' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '96',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '96' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '120' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '120',
SUM(case when datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) > '120' and datediff(hh,a.DateRecv,GETUTCDATE()) <= '10000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Greater'
from mailmessage a
left outer join mailbox b on a.origmailboxid = b.mailboxid
where a.routedate >  '2015-04-21'
and a.status = '0'
and b.MailBoxID IN ('163')
group by name,mailboxid
select mailboxid, name from mailbox
```

**Results**

163 Mailbox Name    39  16  9   8   4   2   1   2   4   2   2   7   9   5   14  18  18  12  9   4   2   3   0   0   2   3   2   0   1

**I would really appreciate some help with this! Thanks in advance**

Comment: You can use access to connect to your db using odbc.  Then you can run the same query as a pass through.

Comment: I have added the ODBC connection to the DB, but I am not sure what you mean by a pass through. Please can you elaborate.

Comment: I have now figured the pass-through. Didnt even realise that function was there. Your a legend. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do the date arithmetic:

```
SUM(iif(datediff("h", a.DateRecv, now()) > 1 and datediff("h", a.DateRecv, now()) <= 2, 1, 0)) as [2]
```

However, this doesn't handle the `GETUTCDATE()` issue.  If `NOW()` doesn't work for you (for some reason), then calculate the value you want and pass it into the query.